# How to grab list of members with human token discordpy

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to grab members from a discord server with a human token and don't know how to as the traditional way only works for bot tokens. any solutions?

traditional way being `for member in guild.members`

Comment: So, you want to grab all members that are not a bot?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `discord.Member.bot` attribute for this.

```
for member in guild.members:
    if member.bot == True:
        #stuff here
    else:
        pass
```

Have a nice day! :)